# Create a token Authentication for my restfull api in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, token, middleware

How is the best way to create a token auth in nodejs for access to api by front-end application?

Comment: jwt token you can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to create a authentication token you can refer JWT-Token:

Token Creation:

```
 const token = jwt.sign({username},'my_secret_key',{ expiresIn: 60*60*24 });
      res.json({
        "success":true,
        "data":data,
        "token":token
      });
```

Token verification:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function checkToken(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.headers['token'];
    if(token) {
      jwt.verify(token, 'my_secret_key',(err,decode)=>{
        if(err) {
          res.json({"status":500,
            "message":"INVALID TOKEN",
            "error":err.message
         });
       } else {
          next();
        }
      })
    } else {
      res.json({"status":500,
      "message":"NO TOKEN PROVIDE",
      "error":"token must be provide in header for endpoint access"
   });
    }
  }
```

You can refer [link here](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: this is the correct answer, everyone who knows anything uses JWT